# Retrieving the Quotient and Remainder in Using polynom

Tags: polynom

How can I retrieve the value of the quotient and the remainder from one synthetic division problem using polynom and insert the quotient into another synthetic division problem. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polynom}

\title{Using Synthetic Division to Find a Polynomial's Zeros}

\begin{document}

\polyhornerscheme[x=-3,stage=8]{x^3+6x^2-x-30}

\polyhornerscheme[x=-3,stage=8]{x^2 + 3x -10}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the polyhorner-based calculation]

Comment: Section 4.6 of the manual shows that you can do `\polydiv\myquotient{x^3+6x^2-x-30}{x+3}` and use `\myquotient` for instance in `\polylongdiv`. But this doesn't seem to work for `\polyhornerscheme`. 